# Edit/change value in CSV file Python

Tags: python, csv

I am self-learning python and trying to solve this question:

> Build a programme that lets a user register with email and password and these information will be stored into users.csv file. After register, a user can use registered email and password to login, a user can change the password after logged in. This is my code:

```
import csv
import shutil
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

def registerUser():
    with open('users.csv', mode='w', newline='') as f:
        fieldnames = ['email', 'password']
        #writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
        print('Please enter your email and password!')
        user_email = input('Enter your new email: ')
        user_pass = input('Enter your new password: ')
        user_pass1 = input('Enter your password again: ')
        if user_pass == user_pass1:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerow({'email': user_email, 'password': user_pass})
            print('Congrat! You are registered!')
        else:
            print('Please try again!')

def loginUser():
    print('Use your registered email and password to login: ')
    email = input('Email: ')
    password = input('Password:')
    with open('users.csv', mode='r') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for p in reader:
            if p['email'] == email and p['password'] == password:
                print('Login successfully!')
                return True
            else:
                print('Try again!')
                return False

def changePassword(email = None, edit_password = None):
    filename = 'users.csv'
    temp_file = NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', delete=False)
    with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile, temp_file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        fieldnames = ['email', 'password']
        new_pass = input('Enter new password: ')
        new_pass1 = input('Enter new password again: ')
        writer = csv.DictWriter(temp_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        for row in reader:
            if edit_password is not None:
                if new_pass == new_pass1 and row['password'] == edit_password:
                    row['password'] = new_pass
                else:
                    print('Try again!')
            writer.writerow(row)
        shutil.move(temp_file.name, filename)
        return True
    return False

active = True
logged_in = False
# main loop
while active:
    if logged_in:
        print('1. Logout \n 2. Change password \n 3. Quit')
    else:
        print('1. Login \n2. Register \n3. Quit')
    choice = input('What would you like to do?').lower()
    if choice =='register' and logged_in == False:
        registerUser()
    elif choice == 'login' and logged_in == False:
        logged_in = loginUser()
    elif choice =='change' and logged_in == True:
        print('Change password!')
        changePassword()
    elif choice == 'quit':
        active = False
        print('Thanks for using our software!')
    elif choice == 'logout' and logged_in == True:
        logged_in = False
        print('Log out successfully!')
    else:
        print('Try again')
```

However, changePassword function does not work. Any thought would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like when you call `shutil.move()` both files are still open.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('users.csv')
df.loc[df['email'] == user_email, 'password'] = new_pass
df.to_csv('users.csv')
```